# Do composite index updates maintain same order as original updates

Tags: google-app-engine

I have read the documentation at the link below, but have this important question still open. Do composite indexes become consistent in the same order as the original entity update? For example, let's say the same indexed property that is part of a composite index gets updated for rec1, rec2, and rec3. The recs get updates one second apart (rec1=T0, rec2=T0+1, rec3=T0+2). As the index updates get fanned out, can one assume that the indexes become eventually consistent in the same order as the updates? IOW, the index consistency for rec1 precedes the consistency for rec2 which precedes the consistency for rec3. Not asking if the consistency is the same one second apart (that is not important), but more simply whether the order for becoming consistent stays the same. Or is it possible that rec3's index will become consistent before rec2 or rec1. Many thanks. -stevep

Link: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write.html

Answer (score 0):

Only Google can reliably answer this question.

OTOH, if you look at the link you provided, under the `Apply Steps` it says:

```
 Since each index can live in a separate location in Bigtable, these writes
 can be fanned out in parallel to multiple tablet servers.
```

Since the indexes are written in parallel on multiple servers, I'd say there is no guarantee that they are written in some order.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes I hope G. replies as it is in their domain, and they've ported to SO so things like this can be documented. Hopefully they think this is important. The question you raised is key. My thoughts are the same, but one element that keeps hope alive is that multiple tablets are used when an index gets sharded (I think). So when updates are to the same entitiy's index, it may be possible that the updates get enqueued to the same tablet servers in order, and are executed in order. If I was hoping order would be maintained for separate entity updates, then likely no hope.